# How to add search bar to a table header such that editing on it acts like this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Please have a look at the behaviour here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pSMlyp8jmZpbpF3HcPM_ZRNg09Sg-dvs/view?usp=sharing

As you can see, clicking on the search bar pushes the table up with it in the header view.

I am trying this but it doesn't act the same:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

The search bar doesn't go up and stays at the same place. What should I be adding here in an order for same to work?

Comment: You can add it to navigation.

Comment: @Kuldeep, but will it then support on iOS 9.3 and 10?